# Import XML File Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to import an existing XML file located on my desktop to my project.
I've tried dragging and dropping the file in my project. But when I attempt to parse the XML file, it wont't recognize the file. Is there someone who can tell me what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:
http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/
to add a file to your project, dragging and dropping is fine, you need to find a way to access that file as in xml